# application and binary files are not getting updated when applying patch where trying to add registry key

Tags: wix, msi-patch

I am trying to create a patch (.msp file) using wix, where I am copying some files to installation path of the application (Program files) and also trying to add registry key.
While installing (using msi) it works fine as expected, binaries are updated.
But when I try to apply the patch it does not work, means binaries are not getting updated.

However, I observed that when I try to apply the patch once again the binaries seem to be updated.
Seems like here I am adding component by providing Guuid.

Question is: Why it works for fresh installation but not when using patch?
Is it possible to add component with new guuid using patch (msp)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I reformatted your question (and fixed a little grammar) to make it more readable. I'm no wix expert, but I guess they will need a little more information about what exactly you did to answer your question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Mainly if you are doing a full upgrade to your application, like adding features, you shouldn't be using a patch. If you need to replace a file or two from a previous installation then you use a patch for a bite size change in your previous msi.

Answer (score 1):

Some more precise information is needed:

"While installing (using msi) it works fine as expected, binaries are updated".

Is this a fresh install or an upgrade of some kind? If it is a fresh install and your install replaces older binaries because they have a lower version then that is to be expected. You're just installing over existing files, although if they were previously installed by an MSI (yours or anyone's) then you may not be updating them correctly.

It is possible to add a component with a patch, but the rules can be complicated. The intent of a patch is mainly to fix existing components, not add them. Also, if you remove a component as part of a patch then the patch will not work properly. The main issue you need to be aware of is the component rules and not breaking them in a patch or an upgrade.

http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/10/18/component-rules-101/

To add components or do any kind of change (other than fixing existing files) the safest thing to do in your situation is a major upgrade.

To find out if you've broken the component rules during an update (like a patch) take verbose log and look for SELMGR messages related to removal of components not being supported. Also set MSIENFORCEUPGRADECOMPONENTRULES =1 so that the update will fail if the rules have been broken.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370093(v=vs.85).aspx

http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/1/4/doing-a-small-update-or-minor-upgrade-in-msi-use/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "While installing (using msi) it works fine as expected, binaries are updated". Here I mean to say when I perform fresh install I am getting the result as expected, I getting the new files copied and registry entry has been added. also my changes done in the application can be seen ie. I am getting the updated application. However, when I try to apply patch using msp file it does not perform these changes. and the upgrade is not seen.